# Adding string in <Class str> array in python3?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, python-requests, httprequest

I have a string like this below

```
data = '[{"cId": "y02", "name": "Test 02", "description": "My Test"}]'
```

I am sending this data in a http request like

```
import requests

headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
}  
response = requests.post('http://localhost:8000/targets', headers=headers,data=data, auth=('user', 'pass'))
```

Now what i would like to do is e.g. i have a string in a variable like..

```
id=str('random string')
```

and i would like to add it in data like this..

```
data = '[{"cId": id, "name": "Test 02", "description": "My Test"}]'
```

But i am not able to add it. I have tried to first convert the entry in json and then adding it into the array. But server sends the exception back. How can i do that?

Comment: did you notice that `data` is a list of dictionaries with 1 element in it?

Comment: i did type(data)  and it shows me <class 'str'>
.

Comment: " I have tried to first convert the entry in json and then adding it into the array. But server sends the exception back. How can i do that?" What did you try, exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could convert it to a list of dicts.Then convert it to str.(With `json` module):

```
import json

data_before = '[{"cId": "y02", "name": "Test 02", "description": "My Test"}]'
tmp = json.loads(data_before)
tmp[0]["cId"] = str('random string')
data_after = json.dumps(tmp)
```

Then use `data_after` it like before:

```
import requests

headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
}
response = requests.post('http://localhost:8000/targets', headers=headers, data=data_after, auth=('user', 'pass'))
```

---

Or pass it as `json` parameter directly in `requests.post`:

```
import json

data_before = '[{"cId": "y02", "name": "Test 02", "description": "My Test"}]'
data_after = json.loads(data_before)
data_after[0]["cId"] = str('random string')
```

Then do:

```
import requests

headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
}  
response = requests.post('http://localhost:8000/targets', headers=headers, json=data_after, auth=('user', 'pass'))
```

Answer (score 0):

data in request.post() should be a :

> Dictionary, list of tuples, bytes, or file-like object to send in the body of the :class:`Request`.

If your data is json formatted, you can load the data and convert the string into a dict using `json.load("<str in json format>")`.